# Why do Windows applications have varying behaviors when saving to recently accessed directories?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, save-as

I'm wondering why certain applications have a different behavior when displaying recently accessed directories in their Windows 'Save As' dialogue boxes. For example, when I use Adobe Photoshop CC, I have the option to select the drop down arrow on the right side of the address bar:

[image]

A list of directories appears, however it is not organized by most recent. It almost seems random which directories it displays. In fact, there are directories that I have never even saved to from the application, which leads me to believe it is not the application that is curating the list, but some Windows function.

In contrast to this, other applications like 3dsMax for example, populate the list based on actual directories visited, and list them in order of when it was last accessed:

[image]

I know these programs implement 'Save As' in different ways because of how the 'Save As' window behaves. In Photoshop users can select the directory path in the address bar and paste a path from the clipboard (or type one in manually).

In contrast, 3dsMax has a slightly different way of allowing this (the address bar at the top is actually a history bar implemented by the application, but users can navigate directories through a drop down style menu, or paste a directory name in the file name field.

These are just examples (each of which have their own strengths and shortcomings), however they demonstrate that there is not a universal behavior that is adapted by all applications when it comes to the 'Save As' window.

I'm confused by all of this because it does seem that all the applications are using some form of an Explorer shell when the 'Save As' function is evoked. I believe these are using an Explorer shell because we can still perform Explorer functions like copy files, make new folders, delete files, and undo actions all while in these windows.

This brings me to my question:

Why do Windows applications have varying behaviors when saving to recently accessed directories when they are all using some form of Explorer shell?

Comment: I think it originates in that Windows doesn't have a standard, well-defined Toolbox for file-pickers. It has various bits & pieces devs are free to choose amongst.

Comment: *Because* there is not a universal behavior that is adapted by all applications when it comes to the 'Save As' window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm confused by all of this because it does seem that all the applications are using some form of an Explorer shell when the 'Save As' function is evoked. I believe these are using an Explorer shell because we can still perform Explorer functions like copy files, make new folders, delete files, and undo actions all while in these windows.

Those two things are not mutually exclusive – it is possible to embed *just* the "ShellFolderView" control (the icon/list view used by Explorer) while still building a completely custom dialog around it, which is what 3dsMax most likely did. It's fairly similar to embedding a standard "button" or "drop-down listbox" control.

Really, that's also what the *standard* Open/Save dialog also does. The standard dialog is not an Explorer window, either – it's just modeled to look a bit like one, but really it's just a dialog window that embeds a ShellFolderView. (Originally in Windows 95 it didn't even have the usual "Explorer" features available; the ability to manage files from within the Open/Save dialog was added in Windows 98.)

(As a specific example that [this project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670/Office-2000-style-File-Dialogs-for-Win-95-98-NT-Me) reminded me of, Office 2000 also brought its own file open/save dialogs with a distinct look (a sidebar and a preview pane, neither of which the standard Windows dialog had at the time); the entire dialog was built custom except for having a *similar* layout and embedding a standard folder-view.)

It is *also* possible to build a custom icon/list view control that provides nearly identical functions. Any program can make new folders, but Explorer itself provides programmatic access to many of its functions – e.g. any program can cause an Explorer-style right-click menu to pop up (complete with the extensions), and any program can request a file deletion to be done through Explorer.

(Third-party file managers such as Total Commander often do so; the file list is custom but the interactions can be directed through the shell if needed. Total Commander handles file move/rename all by itself, as any program can rename a file, but it allows deletion to happen via Explorer so that files would go to Recycle Bin.)